# The sum of the series of the form $\sum_{n=1}^∞ a^n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

> How to find the sum of this series ?  $$\sum_{n=1}^∞ \Big(\frac{4}{9}\Big)^n $$

In General,

Does the series $\sum_{n=1}^∞ k^n$ , where $k$ is a random real number, have the finite sum ?

Comment: Do you mean $n$ in your sums? Your lower indices on the sum are $i$, so any terms in $n$ just come out of the sum....

Comment: ow, sorry, a typo

Comment: There is no $i$ in the summed term $(4/9)^n$,which isn't how sum notation is usually defined.

Comment: I think you should have $i$ somwhere in the body of the summation

Comment: sorry, the i is meant to be n, already edited.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\frac{4}{9})^n$ then you see its a geometric series with common ratio of $\frac{4}{9}$ which is less than 1 guaranteeing convergence of the series.

Thus for $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a r^n = \frac{a}{1-r}$.

So

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\frac{4}{9})^n = \frac{\frac{4}{9}}{1 - \frac{4}{9}} = \frac{4}{5}$.

Comment: Well the same remark as to previous answer: there is no need to answer, when it is just the formula for the sum of geometric progression. A link to wikipedia is enough.

Comment: Ok, BTW which previous answer?,so should I delete this?

Comment: the previous one is deleted ;)